# Socket.io version 2.1.0 error 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I found this error using socket.io latest version: "index.js: 83 POST http: //localhost/socket.io/? EIO = 3 & transport = polling & t = MDUHEO9 404 (Not Found)".
I understand the reason: the true address must be http: // localhost: 3000 / socket.io /.
Do you know how I can correct?

I have read many discussions, but no one has a suitable solution for version 2.1.0, even in a discussion I read a downgrade proposal, I would like to avoid it.

client.js:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io().connect('http://localhost:3000');
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
```

server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: can you show are are you adding `socket.io` js file in your html  ? and how you are serving that from backend

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Thank you for your interest: I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var socket = io().connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

to this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

or to this:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
```

Either of these last two are the same.

---

You will want to use only one form of connect, either `io(...)` or `io.connect(...)`, not both.  When you call just `io()` you're trying to connect to the default URL which will be the URL of the current web page and then when you then try to also do `.connect()` after that, you're trying to connect again.  You only want one connection and to the specified URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've defined any endpoint to server `socket.io` client file. That's why you are getting `404`.

If you've installed in with `npm`, you can allow express to server that kind of static files for you by just adding the following line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

if you've installed `socket.io` with bower, use

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

Or you can place that `socket.io`'s client library at any location and server the file against the requests like

```
app.get('/socket.io', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile("Path to socket.io.js file");
});
```

And you don't need to write full address in

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Just use

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: With the code you have proposed, another error occurs: "ReferenceError: express is not defined" or "GET http: //localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)" depending on the code used. However I used npm to install it.

Comment: remove `var app = require('express')();` line and add `var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  `

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists, I tried again all the possible ways but still nothing.

Comment: just check if it works with adding `cdn` link for socket.io client// something like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>`